# How to access asp.net form server side variables in Knockoutjs

Tags: c#, asp.net, knockout.js, javascript

I'm new to Knockoutjs. I'm just going through [Live examples](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/).

Can someone show me how to access asp.net server side code in Knockoutjs.

Let's say I have below code asp.net and want to populate

> helloWorld

and

> list

to Knockoutjs.

```
string helloWorld = "Hello world";
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("US");
list.Add("UK");
list.Add("Canada");
```

Comment: You will need to render them somehow to make them available to the client-side; for example, in an `asp:literal` or via AJAX. I doubt however you will get a single solution here that will be suitable in all cases.

Comment: There are a few options. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11133642/signalir-and-knockoutjs-in-asp-net-web-form?rq=1) and [this](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't? You need to send back the server side variables as a response to the client (browser in this instance)

If you're using RESTful WCF/MVC/Web API, have you read much about [DataContracts?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127(v=vs.110).aspx).  You can also achieve sending messages to the client using SignalR.

Regardless of the technology, you can't bind to variables stored in memory on the server

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `DataContractJsonSerializer` (from `System.Runtime.Serialization.dll`).

You can write utility class to encapsulate the logic, like:

```
public class JavaScriptStringSerializer {

  public string SerializeString<T>(T value) {
    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
    byte[] buffer;
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
      serializer.WriteObject(stream, value);
      buffer = stream.ToArray();
    }
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
  }

  public T DeserializeString<T>(string value) {
    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
    T result;
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value);
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(buffer, false)) {
      result = (T)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

Then on .aspx page declare literal like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
       var oData = <asp:Literal ID="litServerModel" runat="server" Mode="PassThrough" />;
       // do something with oData - like bind viewmodel, etc
    });
</script>
```

And in codebehind:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptStringSerializer();
litServerModel.Text = serializer.SerializeString<List<string>>(new List<string> { 
  "aa", 
  "bb", 
  "cc" 
});
```

For more complex object you have to decorate them properly with `DataContract`/`DataMember` attributes - like:

```
[DataContract]
public class Point { 
  [DataMember]
  public int X { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public int Y { get; set; }
}

litServerModel.Text = serializer.SerializeString<Point>(new Point { 
  X = 1, 
  Y = 2 
});
```

Comment: This is a WebForms solution which isn't necessarily required as it's unclear as to what stack the poster is using.

Comment: @MarkWalsh: Your answer is just a list of available technology, so not very useful. This is at least a starting point that will work with MVC with some changes too.

Comment: The type or namespace name 'Json' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: Did you include `System.Runtime.Serialization.dll` and the correct `using` statement (`System.Runtime.Serialization.Json`)?

Comment: @PatrickHofman, yep a list of technology in order to achieve what was asked which is more valuable than a copy and pasted solution to a question which was posed without context.  Sometimes guidance rather than happy pasting is more valuable.

Comment: @MarkWalsh - there is separate tag for MVC (ASP.NET MVC); so when someone tags question just ASP.NET I'm assuming web forms.

Comment: @Ondrej Svejdar, that's fair enough (even if WebForms is unfavourable in almost every given scenario), I just wanted to highlight that answering a question without stipulated context is potentially confusing to OP.  The Asp.Net tag should encompass the entire family now, WebForms, MVC, SignalR and Web API.